# How to create S3 bucket with all available permissions ? (on testing with mocha)

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, amazon-s3, mocha.js, amazon-iam

I need to have some generated S3 bucket with all avavilable permissions - 
READ and WRITE are mandatatory.

I tried so far to make it using this code:

```
var createBucketParams = {Bucket: bucketName, ACL: 'public-read-write', GrantFullControl:'FULL_CONTROL'};
S3.createBucket(createBucketParams, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error while calling createBucket() - Error: " + err);
    } else {
        console.log("Successfully Bucket created.");
    }
});
```

My problem is that the permissions are not working well, i'm getting AccessDenied while trying to getObject(), any ideas how to solve it ?

**EDIT:**
This is my current code with all the latest changes:

```
before(() => {
    console.log("Mocking AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient API");

    AWSMock.mock('DynamoDB.DocumentClient', 'put', function(params, callback) {
        callback(null, "Mock: successfully put object in DynamoDB");
    });

    console.log("Mocking AWS.S3 API");

    AWSMock.mock('S3', 'createBucket', function (params, callback){
        callback(null, "successfully bucket created in S3");
    });
    AWSMock.mock('S3', 'putObject', function (params, callback){
        callback(null, "successfully put item in S3");
    });
    AWSMock.mock('S3', 'getObject', function (params, callback){
        callback(null, "successfully get item in S3");
    });
    AWSMock.mock('S3', 'putBucketPolicy', function (params, callback){
        callback(null, "successfully putBucketPolicy in S3");
    });

});


it('Writing a file to S3 with user metadata - when data is valid JSON and updating the DB is Succeed',
    function(done) {

        var bucketName = 'my.unique.bucket.name';
        var fileName = 'fileName.csv';
        var s3Policy = {
            "Version":"2012-10-17",
            "Id":"http referer policy example",
            "Statement":[
                {
                    "Sid":"Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": "*",
                    "Action": ["s3:GetObject,s3:PutObject"],
                    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::" + bucketName + "/*",
                    "Condition": {
                        "IpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "127.0.0.1"},
                        "NotIpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "127.0.0.1"}
                    }
                }
            ]
        };

        var S3 = new AWS.S3();
        var createBucketParams = {Bucket: bucketName, ACL: "FULL_CONTROL", Region: "us-west-2"};
        S3.createBucket(createBucketParams, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error while calling createBucket() - Error: " + err);
            } else {
                console.log("Successfully Bucket created.");
            }
        });

        var putBucketPolicyParams = {
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Policy: JSON.stringify(s3Policy)
        };
        S3.putBucketPolicy(putBucketPolicyParams, function(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
            else     console.log(data);
        });


        var putObjectParams = {Bucket: bucketName,
            Key: fileName,
            Body: 'Hello!',
            Metadata: {startDate: "2016-12-12T12:34:56.000Z", endDate:"2016-12-31T12:34:56.000Z",
            userName:"someUser",
        originalFileName:"fileName.csv"}};
        S3.putObject(putObjectParams, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack)
            } else {
                console.log("Successfully put a file to bucket");
            }
        });


        LambdaTester(myHandler)
            .event(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(require('./testcases/single_record_with_user_metadata.json'))))
            .expectSucceed(function(result) {

                expect(result.valid).to.be.true;
             })
            .verify(done);
    });
```

And the usage in the js file:

```
S3.getObject(s3FileParams, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        var message = "Error while trying to get file object " + fullFileName + " from bucket " + bucketName + ". Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function. Error: " + err;
        console.error(message);
        // console.log(err, err.stack);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        userMetaDataJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.Metadata));
    }
    resolve();
})
```

Comment: Please specify what isn't working.Your post consists of a statement and a piece of code. It does not include a problem or a question.

Comment: @MarkB The permissions are not working well, i'm getting `AccessDenied` while trying to `getObject()`

Comment: Then edit your post to include that key piece of information before someone comes along and closes your question.

Comment: Unrelated to the AccessDenied issue, you should probably use GrantRead and GrantWrite rather than GrantFullControl otherwise all users can rewrite the ACL for the bucket.

Comment: @jarmod could you please share this example ?

Comment: The API docs have the details. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createBucket-property.

Comment: @jarmod what is the 'STRING_VALUE' that I need to use there?

Comment: The documentation here is very poor but I believe that it's asking for a list of grantees, that can include AllUsers, AuthenticatedUsers, LogDelivery, your AWS Account Canonical User ID, or (historically) the email address of an AWS account. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#specifying-grantee.

Answer (score 1):

S3 offers two types of [policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-overview.html):

- resource-based
- user-based

You're (correctly) trying to apply a resource-based policy. For resource-based policies, you have a further two options:

- Access Control Lists (ACL)
- bucket policy

You're trying to apply an ACL in which case you should read the 'Mapping of ACL Permissions and Access Policy Permissions' section in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#specifying-grantee). Specifically, when you grant the READ ACL on a bucket, you are permitting the following:

- s3:ListBucket
- s3:ListBucketVersions
- s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads

Note specifically that you are *not* permitting s3:GetObject. To do that, you would supply the READ ACL on each object when you put objects into the bucket.

OK, all that ACL stuff aside, you should probably be using a bucket policy instead of ACLs. Bucket policies supplement, and in many cases replace, ACL-based access policies. Here is an [example policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2) that grants the s3:GetObject permission to all users. You will also have to add PutObject to allow them to upload (and other actions as necessary for list, delete etc. as appropriate). You can set a bucket policy using [putBucketPolicy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putBucketPolicy-property).

Comment: Could you please show me how to use these policies when creating the bucket ? I didn't understand where do I need to use the policy

Comment: I found some sample code pretty quickly with a Google search: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-bucket-policies.html

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: ` UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Policy' found in params`

Comment: [Working in the dark here] I'm going to guess that you've supplied Policy when calling createBucket when you should supply it to putBucketPolicy.

Comment: Still getting `AccessDenied`

Comment: I would encourage you to debug further. For example, start with a policy that allows all S3 actions to the bucket. Does it work? Next, try to find out which specific action is causing AccessDenied. Why is it failing? Or leverage CloudTrail.

Comment: Please go over my edited question, I think that now it would be much clearer

Comment: Some problems with the latest iteration: ["s3:GetObject,s3:PutObject"] should be ["s3:GetObject", "s3:PutObject"] (it's a list of strings each representing an action; it's not a single string containing a list of actions) and your source IP conditions are contradictory.